# Is it safe to boil water in a foil pan on an electric burner?

Tags: metal, heat

Is it safe to boil water in a foil pan on an electric burner?

Can the metal leach into the water?

I've heard some reports recently about avoiding aluminum foil due to it leaching into food.

Photos of the items in question, below:

[image: Foil pan]

[image: Electric burner]

Comment: Unless the food is acidic, Al won't leach much.

Comment: @IvanNeretin "much" ?

Comment: Not significantly. However this alu pot might just fail, depending on how hot the heater coil becomes. Also you canot properly hold it when hot. Good luck with your hands. My advice is to not do it. Totally inappropriate.

Comment: Personally, I would put a single layer of aluminium over each electric burner (just in case) and then the aluminium container. As long as you regularly check, there should be no problem. And for the aluminium ions entering your body, you may get much more of them from your antiperspirant (depending on which country you live in).

Comment: Never put aluminum foil or thin Al on a burner: it will melt onto the heating element, possibly causing uneven cool and hot spots afterwards. That is not a problem as long as the pan has water, though.

Comment: @Karl I've already been doing it dozens of times. The pan doesn't melt if you set it on low/med and it has water in it. My only question was regarding the safety.